# Angular 2 : iframe is loading in chrome but its not loading in firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, angular, iframe

Am confused why iframe is not loading in firefox. but its working great in google chrome.

Here is my angular 2 code.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 nopadding customPaddingOnMobileDevice" [ngClass]="{visibility: isMapViewHidden}">
   <div [style.height]="(windowHeight - 130) + 'px'">
    <div class="modal-header alert-info">
        <button type="button" class="close" (click)="hideBookingView()">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title text-center">FMA - Book Appointment </h4>
    </div>

    <iframe width="100%" height="790px;" [src]="'https://something.health.care/public/rmd_widget.php?shortname=something&width=1920#doctorLocationsContainer' | safeUrl"></iframe> 
  </div></div>
```

But one thing i observed when chrome loading my map component i can see this iframe url is loading . but in firefox i can't see this iframe url loading.
Anyone faced this kind of issue?
[image: Chome screen shot]

[image: Firefox screen shot]

Comment: Any error messages in the browser console?

Comment: i can't see any errors

Comment: If you investigate the DOM, does the `<iframe>` element have the correct `src="..."` attribute value?

Comment: its working fine with chrome browser, ya i checked in firefox dom url is correct and its showing content also

Comment: That may be. We still need information about what is different in Firefox to track down the root cause. So is Firefox showing the expected `src` attribute value when you inspect the DOM? Does the `<ifram>` contain any content?

Comment: the DOM contain the iframe content its showing properly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129964/discussion-between-appu-amruth-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok finally successfully identified the issue.

Am using ngClass because of that its not working in firefox, but somehow it was working in chrome.

I changed ngClass to *ngIf its working in both the browsers.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 nopadding customPaddingOnMobileDevice animated fadeInDown" [ngClass]="{visibility: bookAppointmentVisibility}">
```

to

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 nopadding customPaddingOnMobileDevice animated fadeInDown" *ngIf="!bookAppointmentVisibility">
```